# Using methods in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have written this method to convert a date:

```
Public Static string ConvertDate(DateTime dt)
{
....
}
```

I want to use this method in Linq Code:

```
var lst = (from L in AllList
           select new { ConvertDate(L.DateReg).ToString(), L.LastName, L.FirstName});
```

But there's an error in the code above. What is the correct code?

Comment: Usually if there is an error, you should _tell us_ what the error is and exactly where it happens.

Answer (score 5):

When defining an anonymous object, the compiler must be able to give names to the properties of the object.  It can do this implicitly for properties, fields and other named variables, but not for method calls.  Give it a name.

```
var query =
    from item in AllList
    select new
    {
        DateReg = ConvertDate(item.DateReg), // lets call it DateReg
        item.LastName,
        item.FirstName,
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lst = (from L in AllList 
       select new { Date = ConvertDate(L.DateReg).ToString(), L.LastName, L.FirstName});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to specify the name of the properties for the anonymous type;

```
var lst = (from L in AllList
           select new { DateReg = ConvertDate(L.DateReg).ToString(), LastName =L.LastName, FirstName = L.FirstName});
```